# What python data type lets me manipulate CSV data the best?

Tags: python, csv, types

I'm trying to keep track of "banned" users in my application.
username,minutes_banned,channel_banned_from

```
joe,5,general
sally,10,other
bob,50,gaming
```

I read the file to a list and it made of list of lists.

I found it hard to work with the data in this form. For example I had trouble getting it to output only usernames.

And I'm also not sure how can I keep track of each set of data. If I take bob as a username and want to check how long hes banned.. How can I relate bob to 50?

Thank you.

Comment: Well, if it's in memory then use a dictionary rather and iterating through a list of lists. But the issue is storing this info in a csv; you could make a really simple (1 hour learning and testing) transition to sqlite in the short term. Then at least you can query the database rather than checking every single line in the CSV.

Comment: This is probably off topic (asking for recommendation), but you should use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html)

Comment: @roganjosh The reason I was storing it in CSV was because I wanted to keep the data intact if the program crashed or if I restarted it.. Can I do the same with dictionaries somehow.

Comment: Not really because it would be in-memory (unless you want something like a NoSQL DB). What I'm suggesting is just to transfer the data from CSV to Sqlite3 (it's built-in to Python) and you can still store the data on disk and do your checks very quickly.

Comment: @roganjosh thank you!

Comment: I'd just write out a json file (assuming you have the data in a dict) rather than using a database

Comment: As an aside, minutes banned is problematic... minutes since when? When setting minutes banned, consider `time.utcnow() + (60 minutes_banned)` and save that instead. When reading later, you check it against current time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a csv formatted file and the `csv` module seems like a good place to start. `DictReader` reads rows into dictionaries, which lets you reference cells by name. You can read a table from there (a `list` of `dicts`). Then, create an index of the fields you want to use the most. The index is another `dict` that references the `dict` s in the table.

```
import csv

with open('banned.txt', newline='') as fp:
    reader = csv.DictReader(fp)
    reader.fieldnames = ['username','minutes_banned','channel_banned_from']
    table = list(reader)

user_index = {entry['username']:entry for entry in table}

user = input('check banned user name: ')
if user in user_index:
    print('banned', user_index[user]['minutes_banned'])
else:
    print('invalid user')
```

Answer (score 3):

If usernames are unique and you don't care about a particular order, keep them in a `dict`:

```
banned = {'joe': (5, 'general'), 'sally': (10, 'other')}
print "Bob's ban duration is", banned.get('bob', 'forever')
```

And you can obtain all the usernames, in indeterminate order, like this: `all_usernames = banned.keys()` which gives `['sally', 'joe']`.

Comment: Until the application crashes and all of the data is lost.

Comment: @roganjosh You can always just pickle the dictionary, and if updates to it are not as frequent, then update the file every time you update it.

Comment: @Antimony True, but I don't understand why you would do that over using sqlite.

Comment: The existing csv format seems reasonable also. There is nothing wrong with pickle, but its a design decision and if OP wants more readable and sharable csv's, then there is no problem with that either.

Comment: @tdelaney I don't think I can argue you on this point as you're more experienced. If CSV is at all appropriate here then I assume I have a personal bias against it, not on objective one.

Comment: Actually, I'm a fan of pickle for intermediate data storage of stuff that is python generated and I think you have a good suggestion for OP. There are other external considerations for data formats - and the (at least kinda) readable csv format is a reasonable one too. We are giving options and they have pluses and minuses.